# Is it possible to change links color in text document in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When editing a plain text file that contains hyperlinks, the links color is the same as the rest of the text. Is it possible to change the links color? I would like the links to be highlighted in the text similar to how it was in the Atom editor. I tried to change token color customizations but it seems that text files do not have a grammar associated with them.

Comment: you can use extension Highlight, add a regex for URLs

Comment: I will give it a try. Though I hoped there could be a plugin-less way to do this. Thank you!